# How to parse webview for Oauth 2.0 code in android

Tags: android, http, oauth-2.0, jsoup, webviewclient

I'm trying to allow users in my android app to log in to their google account so i can access their contacts for the purpose of creating a friends list, and I'm trying to use OAuth to do this. 
So far I have formed the URL and have created the webview which loads the page. I proceed to sign in but i dont know how to assign the code from the URL to the code value in my activity. also i don't know whether my Onpagestarted method is working correctly

**Can someone either tell me either an alternate method/technique to authenticate with google using OAuth2 or tell me what are the issues with my current way as once I reach the page with the code my view remains the WebView and not the textview with the code as I want it to?**

I would like to automate the entire process after the User has signed into the google page in my WebView but so far my code keeps getting stuck at the page with the Authcode which leads me to believe that the Authcode is not being detected by my program.

NOTE: I do not want to simply use the account that is signed into the Android Device (unless obviously the user chooses to enter the same account)

This is the code from the Activity in which I want to acquire the Auth Code/Token and get the Contacts for my User though I don't mind displaying the contacts in a later activity.

```
WebView browser;
final String username = "gotsingh@gmail.com";
 private myWebViewClient client;
String code;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_friends);
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    client = new myWebViewClient();
    WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(client);
    getAuthCode(client);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_friends, menu);
    return true;

}


public void getAuthCode(myWebViewClient myClient){
    browser.loadUrl(url4);
    while (myClient.authCode!= null){
    showCode(myClient);}
}

public void showCode(myWebViewClient myClient){
        code = myClient.authCode;
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText(code);
        setContentView(text);
}
```

Below is my modified WebViewClient class

```
public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
boolean authComplete = false;

String authCode = null;

@Override public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    if (url.contains("?code=") && authComplete != true) {

        int codeStart = url.indexOf("?code=")+6;


        authCode = url.substring(codeStart);    

        Log.i("", "AUTHCODE : " + authCode);
        authComplete = true;

        System.out.println(authCode);

    }else if(url.contains("error=access_denied")){
        Log.i("", "ACCESS_DENIED_HERE");
        authComplete = true;
    }


   }

}
```

Also, if I could get some general guidance on doing POST/GET requests in java to recieve JSON data from google. I am very new to android development and I have close to 0 experience dealing with html/http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this sample](https://docs.auth0.com/android-tutorial). It is not against Google, but the principles are the same. You may want to consider using the "implicit" flow in OAuth to avoid storing secrets in the device.